# Why is NgRx Effects breaking my dependency injection?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, ngrx, ngrx-effects

Im attempting to add ngrx to an existing angular (v14) project. Im new at NgRx...
When i add the NgRx Effects to the app.module it's breaking the DI. When I add myService to the UserEffects it also breaks the DI. If i leave one or the other out then my app works. I'm on v14 and i've tried v15 but no dice.

here's my service - there' nothing in it yet but the dependency of MyService breaks it

```
import { Injectable, Pipe } from '@angular/core';

import { createEffect, ofType, Actions } from '@ngrx/effects';

@Injectable()
export class UserEffects {
  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private _myService: MyService, <-- this breaks it
  ) { }
}
```

Here's my app.module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppLayoutComponent,        
    AppComponent,
  ... lots of components
  ],
  imports: [
    ... lots of modules
    // NgRx
    EffectsModule.forRoot([UserEffects]),
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, { metaReducers }),

    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({ maxAge: 25, logOnly: environment.production }), // should be the last route module
  ],
  providers: [
    AppConfigService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: (oneConfigService: OneConfigService, twoConfigService: ConfigService) =>
        () => oneConfigService.loadAppSettings().then(() => twoConfigService.init()),
      deps: [OneConfigService, ConfigService], multi: true
    },
    ...other providers but i feel that the one above is the problem...
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

here is the console error [image]

I interpret this error stack as the applicationInsights service is trying to get a key from the config service and the config service is undefined

So, my question is how/why does ngrx effects have anything to do with this? I tried a few simple things but can't work out why ngrx is breaking it. Thanks for anything i can try

Comment: Is `MyService` the same as `ApplicationInsightsService`? There's no reference to a `MyService` in the stacktrace so there's really nothing to go on here. You shouldn't rename things if you aren't explaining what is what.

The error itself is kind of clear, something is undefined. Add a breakpoint and check what is undefined..?

Comment: MyService could to be any service in my app. In the error it's the authService. However, it's looking likely this is the problem... https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/931
I didn't see anything in the ngrx guide that explains this, or an approach to fix it.